# How to make an animated spinbox?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to recreate the following widget:

[image]

I made a basic version without animation. Basically, it's a `Row` containing `Text` sandwiched between  2 `IconButton`. The `State`of the widget is updated when one of the buttons is pressed.

```dart
class SpinBox<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> labels;
  final List<T> values;
  final int length;
  final void Function(T newValue)? onChange;
  final int defaultIndex;

  SpinBox(
      {required this.labels,
      required this.values,
      T? defaultValue,
      this.onChange})
      : assert(labels.length == values.length),
        length = labels.length,
        defaultIndex = defaultValue == null ? 0 : values.indexOf(defaultValue);

  @override
  _SpinBoxState<T> createState() {
    return _SpinBoxState();
  }
}
```

```dart
class _SpinBoxState<T> extends State<SpinBox<T>> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _currentIndex = widget.defaultIndex;
    super.initState();
  }

  void _next() {
    if (_currentIndex < widget.length - 1) {
      setState(() {
        _currentIndex++;
        widget.onChange?.call(widget.values[_currentIndex]);
      });
    }
  }

  void  _prev() {
    if (_currentIndex > 0) {
      setState(() {
        _currentIndex--;
        widget.onChange?.call(widget.values[_currentIndex]);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _prev();
            },
            icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.caretLeft)),
        Expanded(
          child: Text(
            widget.labels[_currentIndex],
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
        IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _next();
            },
            icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.caretRight)),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

It works, but I would like to add animations like shown on the GIF.

My question is, how can I implement the *slide in/out* and *fade in/out* animation.

Comment: why not to use existing `PageView` and just call `PageController.animateToPage`?

Answer (score 0):

[AnimatedSwitcher](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2W7POjFb88g) can be a good option for this type of widget. By default it can create pretty smooth looking simple animations but for this scenario, you need to customize the transition to match with your reference. You can learn more about it from this [Medium Article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/what-do-you-know-about-aniamtedswitcher-53cc3a4bebb8)